# Cómo configurar Qt para que ejecute leyendo los datos de un archivo txt

Tags: c++, linux, consola, unix

Tengo mi programa en Qtcreator ya hecho y funcionando pero para ejecutarlo necesito hacer por consola `./programa < datos.txt` (para que lea todos los datos de un archivo txt).

¿Alguien sabe configurar el Qt para que haga eso a la hora de ejecutarlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la barra lateral de QtCreator, en la sección "*Projectos*", seleccionas el proyecto actual y te aparecen las diferentes configuraciones de compilación (normalmente *debug* y *release*). Selecciona aquella en la que quieras aplicar la configuración y después localiza la opción "*run*" (lamento no ser más explícito sobre dónde encontrar esta opción pero cambia entre versiones de QtCreator.

Bien, en esa sección hay un texto cuya etiqueta dice "*Argumentos de línea de comandos*" o, en mi caso "*Command line arguments*". Introduce ahí las opciones de arranque (en tu caso "`< datos.txt`") y listo.

Comment: Lo he intentado pero me sale:[ /bin/sh 1 cannot open such file or directory].

Comment: @Danielmagox Prueba "`< ./datos.txt`" o pasa la dirección absoluta del fichero. Puede que el directorio de trabajo no sea el que esperas.

Answer (score 0):

Vale al final conseguí hacerlo de la siguiente forma:
Se pone la ruta absoluta tal como indicó el compañero anteriormente para correr el programa pero esto dará un problema a la hora de usar el debugger debido a que ya el Qtcreator no va a "saltarse" el proceso de debug en c++.
Para arreglar esto debemos ir a la pestaña debug, y configurar lo para que arranque el debugger desde ahí y poner la ruta absoluta del comando.
Otra opción es quitar correr in terminal en la pestaña ejecución pero puede que así no funcione.